# How to rename header line in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this in R:

```
dataframe <- read.table(file="~/Desktop/prs_profile.txt", header = T, sep="\t")

     FID......IID..PHENO....CNT...CNT2....SCORE
1 1032   468768     -9     74      9 0.00864209
2  1405   468769     -9     92      7 0.0084487
3  1564   468770     -9     92     10 0.0100944
4 1610   468771     -9     92     10 0.00902744
5  998   468774     -9     86      6 0.00773592
6  975   468775     -9     90      8 0.00729964
```

Each header word should correspond to a column however when I print the header, it does not exist as separate column names e.g.

```
> colnames(dataframe)

[1] "FID......IID..PHENO....CNT...CNT2....SCORE"
```

I want to replace the header line so I have tried the following but get an error:

```
names(dataframe) <- c("FID", "IID", "PHENO", "CNT", "CNT2", "SCORE")

Error in names(dataframe) <- c("FID", "IID", "PHENO", "CNT", "CNT2",  : 
  'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

I have read other similar posts here on stackoverflow but this does not apply to my case e.g.

```
> setnames(OedemaG2_PRS, c("FID", "IID", "PHENO", "CNT", "CNT2", "SCORE"))
Error in setnames(OedemaG2_PRS, c("FID", "IID", "PHENO", "CNT", "CNT2",  : 
  Can't assign 6 names to a 1 column data.table
```

Comment: You should try to change the `sep` argument in `read.table` to fit the actual delimiter in your text file. Have you try `sep = " "` instead of `sep = "\t"`?

Comment: You cannot change your column names, because you read in your data incorrectly. As benson23 mentioned you used the wrong separator in `read.table` and everything is imported into a single column instead of the expected 6 columns. As a result you encounter errors when trying to supply your data.frame with 6 column names, because you only have 1.

Comment: Your text file is read as a one-column data frame because of the wrong setting of `sep`. You should provide the content of the text file, e.g. copy/paste the first 5 lines to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dataframe with only 1 column. After reading it, try applying a "data.frame" function in it and see if the number of columns become 6.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(read.table(file="~/Desktop/prs_profile.txt", header = T, sep="\t"))
```

Then, you can try to pass the name(dataframe) as you did.
If it still does not work, the problem is with your database.
You have to read it in such a way that 6 columns are found.

Answer (score -1):

For change columns use colnames()

```
colnames(dataframe) <- c("FID", "IID", "PHENO", "CNT", "CNT2", "SCORE")
```

If you want to change rows, you can use rownames() like colnames().

Comment: can you send your data with 'dput(dataframe)'